# How do you call a method from the view in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I did this:

script/generate controller home

And in the home controller made a the method..

```
def say
  puts "You are here"
end
```

How would I call that method in the index.html.erb?

When learning ruby it just said to run the whatever.rb in the terminal
to run what ever code you wrote within that file. Just curious on how
that would work with rails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we call a Controller's method from a view (as we call from helper ideally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906527/can-we-call-a-controllers-method-from-a-view-as-we-call-from-helper-ideally)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you have a rails server running?

Theres two possibilities, firstly you could make say a helper method in the controller by using:

```
helper_method :say
```

in your controller.

Alternatively, the better solution would be move your say method to the home_helper(?).rb helper file.

you can call this by just using <% say %> in your view file.

Note that a `puts` well put whatever is in your string to STDOUT, not output in your views, if all you wanna do is write a bit of text, you would be better off with just outputting a string and using the erb output mechanism in your view, e.g.

application_helper.rb

```
def say
  "hello"
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= say -%>
```

puts is very useful for unit test debugging where you wanna find out the contents of an object

```
puts @some_object.inspect
```

Whereas if you want output to the log, you could do something like:

```
logger.error "hello"
```

Comment: For some reason I could not get it to work when putting it in the application_helper.rb and calling it with <%= say -%>. I did though get it to work when I add "helper_method :say" to the top of the controller and calling it with <%= say %> with the equal sign. Thanks for pointing me in good direction.

Answer (score 4):

In short: You don't do that.

What you do is: 
You call an action on a controller. For each action, there is a corresponding view, e.g. "say.html.erb" in the directory views/home.
To call that action, and display its corresponding view, you could do something like `<%= link_to 'Say it', :controller => 'home', :action => 'say', :someadditionalparameter => 'foo' %>` in your index.html.erb

If you wanted to access `:someadditionalparameter` in the `say` action, you would do so with `params[:someadditionalparameter]` and would, in this case, get `'foo'`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the view doesn't usually call the controller - it goes the other way around, from what I know. The request comes in, Rails parses the URL according to your config/routes.rb routes, and it forwards the request to the appropriate action in the appropriate controller. By default, Rails supplies a route for /controller_name/action_name, so you can use that for simple messing around with what Rails does for you.

After the controller has run, Rails automatically renders the associated view, which by convention has the same name as its action. The automatically-used view for your 'say' action in the 'home' controller would be found in your directory structure under app/views/home/say.html.erb. You can override this automatic view rendering by calling `render` in your controller action, for example `render :template => :index`.

And lastly, like Konstantinos said, you need to start the server before you can browse to the site in a web browser. It'll be at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` by default; to reach the home controller's say action, you'd go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/say`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to run the rails application

you do that by going to your rails app root directory from command line and you enter

```
ruby script/server
```

then open your browser and type `http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/say`

This should point you to the controller home, action say

Edit: As the rest of people said and i forgot to mention is that you will need a view ( a file by convention located under `app/views/CONTROLLER_NAME/ACTION_NAME.html.erb` in your example is app/views/home/say.html.erb) if you don't have such a file your action won't be shown and you will be get an error.