# Can we call a Controller's method from a view (as we call from helper ideally)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails MVC, can you call a controller's method from a view (as a method could be called call from a helper)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    # Lots of stuff
  end
  helper_method :my_method
end
```

Then, in your view, you can reference it in ERB exactly how you expect with `<%` or `<%=`:

```
<% my_method %>
```

Answer (score 23):

You possibly want to declare your method as a "helper_method", or alternatively move it to a helper.

[What do helper and helper_method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do)

Answer (score 9):

Haven't ever tried this, but calling public methods is similar to:

```
@controller.public_method
```

and private methods:

```
@controller.send("private_method", args)
```

See more details [here](http://teachmetocode.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-accessing-controller-methods-from-your-view/)

Answer (score 9):

make your action helper method using `helper_method :your_action_name`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def foo
    # your foo logic
  end
  helper_method :foo

  def bar
    # your bar logic
  end
  helper_method :bar
end
```

Or you can also make all actions as your helper method using:  `helper :all`

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper :all

   def foo
    # your foo logic
   end

   def bar
    # your bar logic
   end
 end
```

In both cases, you can access foo and bar from all controllers.