# Rails alias_method to current_user for two user models (Devise, CanCan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I am using Devise with two user types, Employer and Candidate which are largely different from each other.  There is no STI, and one model + Devise authentication for each, currently.  When implementing CanCan for authorization, I found that an alias of current_candidate or current_employer to current_user was needed.  It appears that only one alias can be used to current_user so the non aliased user type cannot be authorized for any actions.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  alias_method :current_user, :current_candidate
  #alias_method :current_user, :current_employer
  #^ can't use both simultaneously!
end
```

The above trips up authorization of employer actions since only the current_candidate can be aliased to current_user which is used in CanCan's current_ability method.

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= ::Ability.new(current_user)
end
```

Is there a way to effectively alias both user types to current_user for CanCan?  Or is there some type of before method that can set current_user without the alias?  Happy to add more code if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the `current_user` method yourself.  It could, for example, go in `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_user
  if current_candidate    # You could use candidate_signed_in? instead.
    current_candidate
  else
    current_employer
  end
end
```

Then it should be available in all your controllers and will be used by CanCan's `current_ability` method.  If you want it available in views too, one option is to then add the line `helper_method :current_user` to `ApplicationController`.

Another option is to override the CanCan `current_ability` method to give the same effect as the above code by adding this to your `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= ::Ability.new((candidate_signed_in?) ? currrent_candidate : current_employer)
end
```

Comment: The first option seems to have worked, although I added an elsif condition to check if current_employer.  Is there a way to initialize a non-model user type when a visitor hasn't signed in/up?

Comment: I think I resolved the non-model user situation by setting current_candidate to Candidate.new without saving it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you wanted it to return a non-nil value if nobody was logged in. In that case, yes, an elsif for the `current_employer` and a new object for the non-logged-in case could do the trick.  I guess a new `Candidate` object doesn't then give the user abilities you don't want them to have?!  Otherwise you could use some other class representing a Guest or something, or just have it return nil as in my answer and cope with that case (current_user == nil) in your controllers/views.  You could also define a `user_signed_in?` method which checked candidate/employer_signed_in? methods.

Comment: The abilities are restricted for Candidates based on their id, so it's not a risk to set the guest users to a Candidate object.  Good thought.

Comment: Note that this new `current_user` won't be accessible in your views, you need to declare it as a `helper_method` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18659606/1533054

Comment: Indeed, as I had mentioned in my answer :)