# Calling method from view Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

how can i call the method get_data from my view index.html.erb?

> class CalculationController < ApplicationController
>         def index
>                 #------------------Module1-----------------------------------------
>
> ```
>       #From json to hash - consumption_profile_generic 
>       file_gen = File.read("consumption_profile_generic_some_columns.js") 
>   @data_hash_gen = JSON.parse(file_gen) 
>
>   #Passing variable introduced by the user in mod1
>   @user_entry_module1 = params[:user_entry_module1]
>
>   # Filtering date and consumption_% ind 2 vectors and then merging them
>   num = @data_hash_gen.count 
>   @vectorA = Array.new
>   @vectorB = Array.new
>   i = 0
>   while num > i
>       @vectorA[i] = @data_hash_gen[i]["consumption_%"].to_f * @user_entry_module1.to_i
>       @vectorB[i] = @data_hash_gen[i]["date"]
>       i += 1
>   end
>
>   @vectorC = @vectorB.zip(@vectorA)   
>
> end
>
> def get_data
>       @cuca = 2
>
> end
>
> end
> ```

I want that the variable @cuca will be printed on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we call a Controller's method from a view (as we call from helper ideally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906527/can-we-call-a-controllers-method-from-a-view-as-we-call-from-helper-ideally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a helper method, add this line to the controller

```
helper_method :get_data
```

Then in the view you can write `<%= get_data %>` to show the value stored in `@cuca` variable.

Hope this help!

Comment: And how can i call it from my view? <% get_data %> <%= @cuca %> ?

Comment: This should set `@cuca` to 2, and then you show the value of `@cuca`, so your code above should just render out "2".

Comment: Use `<%= get_data %>` in the view, I have edited the answer, check it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your app doesn't have a route for your `get_data` method, you should just move it to a model (i.e. `Calculation`) as a class or instance level method.

You can then set the value in an instance variable in your index action and use it in your view.