# Can't access helper method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I get the error :

```
undefined local variable or method `url_to_submit_event'
```

when i'm trying to access an helper method from a form in my html.haml.

The html looks like this (the method i'm trying to call is url_to_submit_event) :

myproject/app/views/myengine/form.html.haml :

```
= form_for @event, url: url_to_submit_event(@event) do |f|
  .row
    .col-md-12.no-padding
      .whitebg.padding15
        .form-group.user-info-block.required
          = f.label :title, t('myght_default_events.events.form.title'), class: 'control-label'
          = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'
```

and the helper goes like this :

myproject/app/helpers/myengine/event_helper.rb :

```
module MyghtDefaultEvents
  module EventHelper
    def url_to_submit_event(event)
      if event.new_record?
        myght_default_events.events_new_path
      else
        myght_default_events.events_update_path(event.id)
      end
    end
    end
  end
```

At the moment i've tried to add my helper and my method manually in my event_controller but it doesn't work. I've already used a helper the same way and I see no difference in the code, do you have any idea what can be missing here?

My events are in an engine outside of this project but i've made the links between the two projects already, here is the controller just in case :

myengine/app/controllers/myengine/events_controller :

require_dependency "myght_default_events/application_controller"

```
module MyghtDefaultEvents #:nodoc:
  class EventsController < ApplicationController #:nodoc:

    before_action :set_event, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

*various methods*


  end
end
```

Usually naming it correctly is enough to access it from views so I don't get why I have an error here.

Comment: shouldn't that helper method be part of the `Event` model?

Comment: I'm on an already existing project and they used the same way for another model, the url to submit is an helper so if I want to keep this logic I can't put that in my model

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906527/can-we-call-a-controllers-method-from-a-view-as-we-call-from-helper-ideally

Comment: yeh it works that way but I need to use an external helper file, not put that method in my controller

Comment: Including EventHelper inside controller might help.