# Getting Method Not Defined Trying To Call Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I know this should be easy, but can't really find a straight answer on how im supposed to be calling a method from html.erb.

On my edit page, I want to run a simple time calculation (current time - start time from DB).

I trying to call the method using

```
Time: <% totalhours(@timetracker.time_start, @time_now) %>
```

In my timetracker contoller edit action I have

```
  def edit
   
    def totalhours(starttime, endtime)
      totalhourscalc = (Time.parse(endtime) - Time.parse(starttime) / 3600)
      p totalhourscalc
    end

  end
'''

The error im getting is "undefined method `totalhours' for #<ActionView::Base:0x007f244820cc90>    {highlighted} Time: <% totalhours(@timetracker.time_start, @time_now) %>" {/highlighted}

I have tried multuple variations and spent last couple of hours trying to find a simple answer. Help would be greatly appreciated on what im doing wrong.

Thank you in advance!!!!!!!
```

Comment: You can call helpers, you can call objects on a method, you can access instance values you set in the action; you can't call arbitrary things you define. Off you're just going to set a value in the controller, just expose there *result* as an instance variable. But define the method as a private method if it's not intended to be a general purpose helper.

Comment: Define your totalhours method outside of edit, but still in the Controller class.  Then add `helper_method :totalhours`. Is this what you want to do? Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906527/can-we-call-a-controllers-method-from-a-view-as-we-call-from-helper-ideally

Comment: Both of these answers were extremely helpful. Thank you both.