# Demystifying Ruby ERB Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Ruby on Rails newbie question...

Consider the following code (which is within a view):

```
<div class="meta">
<%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at) + " ago", status %> |
<span class="admin">
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_status_path(status) %> |
<%= link_to "Delete", status, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Ya sure?" } %>
</span>
</div>
```

Some of methods called within the ERB tags seem like magic to me, and I'm trying to demystify them. I don't feel comfortable using code if I don't understand how it works under the hood.

Can someone point me to where the following methods (er, I think they are methods, maybe that's not the right term) are defined and/or documented?

- edit_status_path()
- :delete
- data:
- confirm:

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of `Symbol`s in Ruby? If not, you should go have a goo Ruby/Rails book/tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one method here: `edit_status_path`. It is created within you routes file (`config/routes.rb`), most likely by another moethod called `resources` (in this case it would be `resources :statuses`).

`:delete` is not a method, it is a symbol: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html

`data:` alone has no meaning in ruby, it always comes with a second part (like `data: value`). It is ruby syntax for Hash object: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html, using symbols for keys. So

```
{a: 1}
```

is the same as

```
{:a => 1}
```

`I don't feel comfortable using code if I don't understand how it works under the hood.` - I understand you completely. I strongly advise you to read some ruby book (not ruby on rails) before you start learning rails (and then start with a good book as well). The fact I started learning ruby from rails was the reason why I hated this language for couple of months before I fall for it.

Comment: If reading a book sound boring, the [Codecademy Ruby Track](http://codecademy.com/tracks/ruby) is a nice interactive way to learn the basics.

Comment: @BroiSatse: Thanks. I think your comment is moving me in the right direction. However, when I look in my routes.rb file, I only [this](https://gist.github.com/jonathancadepowers/76b6627bec6200d3df21). Unless I'm missing something here, I don't see anywhere that edit_status_path is defined.

Comment: @BroiSatse: Nevermind. I found the answer to my question [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html). "Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring separate routes for your index, show, new, edit, create, update and destroy actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of code."

Comment: After more research, running `rake routes` helps you see exactly which routes are associated with your Rails project, including the ones that are **implied** (versus explicitly defined in a file within your project).

Answer (score 1):

**ERB**

ERB code is basically `Ruby` / `Rails`' way of dynamically handling code (like `PHP`'s `<$ $>`). The use of ERB code is basically just about calling methods & classes which utilize the pre-processing power of Rails

To demystify your code, and as stated by `@BroiState`, you have several elements to consider:

--

[**Methods**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378000/how-do-you-call-a-method-from-the-view-in-rails)

```
edit_status_path(status)
```

This is a Rails method to [render a path](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (which will basically output `domain.com/path/to/your/controller`

As mentioned, this will be derived from your `config/routes.rb` file. However, what I want to express the role **`methods`** play in your code. Every time you call a `mysterious` method in Rails, you're basically tapping into the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - which means you're using the methods available to your `view`.

***Every* piece of ERB functionality is a `method` or `object`**

In Rails' case, these are typically known as [`helper` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992659/in-rails-what-exactly-do-helper-and-helper-method-do), which can both be explicitly declared (in `app/helpers`), or implicitly declared (inside `Rails`).

Many of the path helpers will be defined inside the Rails framework, which is why they seem mysterious. However, as you gain more experience, you'll see [many different Rails Classes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) which define many of the mysterious methods - allowing you to gain a more intimate view of how this works

--

**Arguments**

The famous [`:symbol`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html) is a ruby module which basically allows you to define a temporary object, ready to be populated with data (I think)

All of the `method: :delete` etc - are all arguments for the methods you're using in your views. *Every* method you use has arguments, and many of them will be symbols.

ERB is basically just a case of using methods & objects, and your `:arguments` essentially allow you to use different methods in your views